# How do lightnings have matter but light doesn’t?

Tags: visible-light, lightning

if lightning is plasma which is a state of matter that means that lightnings have matter. but light is electromagnetic radiation and doesn’t have matter?
can someone please explain?
thanks

Comment: LIght bulbs are made of matter and produce light. So are candle flames. So is the Sun. What is it about lightning that makes you think it can't both be made of matter and produce light?

Answer (score 1):

the glowing part of a lightning discharge consists of atoms which have had some of their electrons torn off. Atoms have mass, and therefore so does the glowing part of a lightning bolt.

Those (massive) atoms are so hot that they themselves are giving off light. That light carries away energy, but it has no mass.